# php fill a select with an array - getting strange value

Tags: php

I am trying to fill a select with the result array of a query. ExecuteRows is a function that connects up to my Sqlite db and returns an array of columns.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT empid, fullname FROM employees ORDER BY fullname";
     $rows = ExecuteRows($sql);
     echo "<select>";
     foreach($rows as $r) {
     echo "<option value=' $r.empid '> $r.fullname </option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";
?>
```

The resulting dropdown values of the select are the right number of rows that I would expect but display a value of "Array.fullname" and the html in the page shows

```
<option value=' Array.empid '> Array.fullname </option>
```

I am not sure what I did wrong. I expected to see the actual empid and fullname values.

Can you help point out any issues?

Comment: I think you want `{$r['empid']}`, not `$r.empid`, same for `$r.fullname`

Comment: `.` for accessing properties is from javascript. In php `.` is for concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access an array, so use the [] syntax.

```php
echo "<option value='" . $r['empid'] . "'>" . $r['fullname'] . "</option>";
```